# Quicksight Lookup Values in Another Table

Tags: reporting, amazon-quicksight

Below is example of I have a table called account which is the user. The user is in an  organization but we only store the org id.

What I'm currently doing is using an calculated field and the ifelse function but there are a number of other areas with a lot of entries so a lot of work to create all these calculated fields.

Is there a smarter way to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to add a join between the 2 tables.

- Add both datasets (user and orgs)
- In the user dataset, use the "add data"
- Select the org dataset
- Use a join and it will look something like this:

[image]

You are probably past this point by now but at least an answer is here now